# How can I use Varnish Edge Side includes for a sidebar?

Tags: varnish

I've read this post here but am unsure where to start. https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ESIfeatures

Edit for clarification:
I do want to use Full page caching but once we cache say the article page, it can stay in the cache for a day or so, or if something pushes it out. But I'd Want the sidebar to refresh at a faster rate

Comment: Why will you want to do something like that? It will probably not save you the effort of implementing some caching, so you might as well cache full pages instead of partials.

Comment: Please be more specific on a problem you actual face, WPSE answers are based on solutions.

Comment: Sorry. I do want to use Full page caching but once we cache say the article page, it can stay in the cache for a day or so, or if something pushes it out. But I'd Want the sidebar to refresh at a faster rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

If you have a sidebar called "Sidebar"

```
<?php
if ( !dynamic_sidebar("Sidebar") ) :
endif;
?>
```

You wrap it in ESI tags, one for if ESI is not enabled and one if it is:

```
<esi:remove>
  <?php
  if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Sidebar") ) :
  endif;
  ?>
</esi:remove>
<!--esi
<esi:include src="/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/esihandler.php"/>
-->
```

Then, create the endpoint that ESI will pull from, call it esihandler.php:

```
<?php
$cwd = getcwd();
$path = substr($cwd, 0, strpos($cwd, 'wp-content/'));
require $path . 'wp-blog-header.php';

if ( !dynamic_sidebar("Sidebar") ) :
endif;
```

Finally, update your varnish config for the appropriate cache times in the sub vlc_fetch call:

```
if (req.url ~ "esihandler.php") {
  set beresp.ttl = 10m;
}
else {
  set beresp.do_esi = true;
  set beresp.ttl = 1440m;
}
```

Comment: That will work with one sidebar, but what do you do when you have more then one? you probably need to pass the id of the sidebar somehow,  maybe as a parameter.

Comment: Very true. My post was just meant as a starting point

Comment: What happens if I don't specify the `<!--esi ... -->` section? Will it break or will it just exclude the content within `<esi:remove>` and serve the cached contents without it? Is the `sub vcl_fetch` endpoint to `esihandler.php` mandatory? EDIT: oh I just misunderstood the logic, nevermind.